Is it possible to show the Other Users option without hiding available users on the lock screen?
I have a hidden user on my computer. To log into it, I need to disable show last logged in user in the group policy. Unfortunately, this hides all of the available users and I need to type in the username to log into these accounts. Is is possible to show the Other Users option but have the accounts still visible? It seems that this was possible on older versions of windows, but I'm not sure if I can do it on Windows 11.
Here's an image of what I want (ignore the red box around the password reset button):
Other Users button on lock screen

You can have both.

@Ramhound How do I do that?

Can’t….darn you autocorrect!

You can make several different settings on the Windows 11 Login screen both via GPO and via the System Registry.
Make sure your user and others are not part of the Active Directory domain.
See this link for user configuration options on the login screen:
https://woshub.com/how-to-show-all-users-accounts-on-windows-10-login-screen/

Unfortunately, the article does not solve my problem. I can hide the list of available users, to log into the hidden one, but I cannot have a field to input a user name and have a list of users at the same time.

@Daniel Eremin You posted an image of what you want in your question... could you also post an image of what your login screen currently looks like, so we can see the differences between them?

Okay, here's a picture of the lock screen both with and without the group policy setting changed.
